# Method parameters (void) vs no void declaration (error from compiler)

Tags: objective-c

Why the compiler gives an error in this case of method declaration -

```
-(void) someMethod (void);
```

But approves this -

```
 -(void) someMethod;
```

(SomeClass.h)

I've read that it is better to declare (void) in parameters than not declaring, but probalby I miss some point.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You cannot do this for Objective-C.

In Objective-C, every parameter must be after `:` e.g.

```
- (void)someMethod:(int)i;
- (void)someMethod:(int)i withString:(NSString *)string;
- (void)someMethod:(int)i :(int)i2 :(int)i3; // you can do this but is bad style
```

and it does not make sense to make something like

```
- (void)someMethod:(void)what_goes_here;
```

so if you want a method without parameter:

```
- (void)someMethod;
```

However you can do it in C/C++

```
void someMethod(void);
```

And I didn't see any benefit of declare void parameters (explicitly declare things is not always good).

Comment: The benefit in C is to comply with the C standard - 6.11.6: «The use of function declarators with empty parentheses (not prototype-format parameter type declarators) is an obsolescent feature.»

Comment: @xlc I've never seen this "limitation" written in any source I read about Obj-C. Must to write it. Thanks for clarification

Comment: @xlc is - someMethod; is equivalent to -(void) someMethod; ?

Comment: @llan, `- someMethod` can be used instead of `- (id)someMethod`, but I've never once seen it (in 8 years of ObjC programming), and it would be bad style to use it. Note that the assumed return type for a method with no explicitly declared return type is *not* `void`, it's `id`.

Comment: @llan `- someMethod` is legacy ObjC style. Just like legacy C, you can declare method without return type and compiler assume it return int. In this case ObjC will make it return `id`

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on @xlc's answer

The answer is a difference in syntax between Objective-C and "normal" C/C++.

Way back in the origins of Unix and C days, late 60's/early 70's, when declaring (not defining) a function, you didn't need to specify how many arguments it accepted, or what types they needed to be. Nor did you need to specify whether or not it returned a value.

Later, folks realized that this would be a good idea, both for better error detection at compile time and for greater efficiency of generated code.  So implementers added the ability to specify argument types in the function declaration. This was standardized as part of ANSI C in the late 80's.

However, there was a need to retain backwards compatibility with existing code. So a function declaration of `foo()` couldn't be assumed to mean "function with no arguments". To solve this, the `void` keyword was introduced. That allowed you to say `foo(void)` to mean "function named foo which takes no arguments".

When Objective-C was invented in the 90's, they added a new syntax for defining methods. Because there was no legacy code to deal with, they simply said that a method has to declare all its arguments; if there are none, then the method takes no arguments.

Objective-C still uses the `void` keyword to indicate that a method returns no value, though.

Comment: thanks for a great Hx (Historic) aspect of the void-issue. Important for deep understanding. Upvote